# Is there an application for creating an text inventory of media files and/or applications

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, finder, filesystem, dropbox

For insurance purposes, I would like to keep a list of the following:

- All of the movie files on my Mac
- All of the music files on my Mac
- All of the applications on my Mac

The lists needs to be updated regularly, and stored in the cloud (not iCloud). Being able to save the list files to a dropbox folder would be just fine. It should also be able to index network locations.

These files are from multiple sources, so I can not rely on the 'Purchased' functionality on iTunes (for example).

Is anyone aware of an application that can do this? I could not find much on Google.

Answer (score 4):

I would say the best way to do this would be some sort of script that searches your drive on a scheduled basis, and dumps the results into a text file for you.

Something like:

```
sudo find / -name "*.avi" -o -name "*.mp4" -o -name "*.m4v" -o -name "*.mp3" > ~/Dropbox/results.txt
```

The -o switch is the `find` equivalent of logical OR, so the above is searching the whole of your computer for any files (or directories) that have the extensions .avi, .mp4, .m4v, or .mp3

Comment: Thanks. I'm considering using something like this but wanted to check first what is out there. If not, maybe there's a way to do it with Hazel or something.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [Delicious Library 2](http://www.delicious-monster.com/)!

It allows you to create a catalogue of books, movies, software and many more from your physical CDs, books, or games by scanning the barcodes.

For digital media it does have support for Kindle ebooks out of the box, however if you want to add other digital media such as video or non-iTunes music, then you have to add it manually as there are no processes to find or import these items except those you write yourself using AppleScript.

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: @patrix Done! See the edited answer.

Comment: Delicious Library 2 is not a program with an automated process to find and catalog digital media; nor does it actually categorise digital media with the exception of music already in iTunes

Comment: @StuWilson He didn't asked for an automated process. Probably the books example wasn't appropriate. I modified the answer.

Comment: @lucaghera Agreed, it's not specifically requested an as automated process however it is inferred from the question such as where it says "It should also be able to index network locations."  I've edited your edit, to be more accurately reflect the DL2 capabilities.

Comment: @StuWilson Thanks, now the answer is surely better!